Gmail search query not working in postman
I am using gmail api to fetch messages. I am giving the request parameter as: "from:xyz@gmail.com is:unread".
Here I am not getting messages in response when my mailbox has one.
Note that the same query works in gmail search tool.

Request details:
Request URL: https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q="from:xyz@gmail.com is:unread"
Request Scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly
Response: {
"resultSizeEstimate": 0
}
Any inputs? Thanks in advance :)

Worked with this query:
https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q="from:xyz@gmail.com" AND "is:unread"

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
